# Tempo de envio de dados

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estou a desenvolver uma pequena estação de meteorologia para aplicar num terreno agricola, que consiste em ter um sensor de temperatura, um sensor de chuva e um sensor de humidade este a incoporar mais tarde pois ainda não o tenho.
No entanto queria pôr a enviar  os dados de temperatura com um delay de 600000ms e que o sensor de chuva tivesse um delay de 1000. Não estou ver a forma como faze-lo. 
O que fiz de código até agora é o seguinte:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <farmerkeith_BMP280.h>

int rainSensor = A0;
int rainLED = 2;
int dryLED = 3;
int sensorVal;
int sensortrigger = 350;
/*
   Conexao ao AP
   Credenciais de acesso
   SSID - Nome do AP de acesso
   Password - Passsword de acesso
*/
#define wifi_ssid "xxxxxxxx"
#define wifi_password "xxxxxxxxx"
/*
   Endereço IP do MQTT Broker (Mosquitto)
*/
#define mqtt_server "192.168.1.10"
/*
   Definição dos tópicos dos dados dos sensores
*/
#define bmp_temperature_topic "temperaturebmp"
#define bmp_pressure_topic "pressurebmp"
#define rain_sensor_topic "rainstate"

/*
   Inicialização das classes
*/
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
bmp280 bmp0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(rainSensor, INPUT);
  pinMode(rainLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dryLED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(rainLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dryLED, LOW);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  bmp0.begin();
}
void setup_wifi() {
  delay(10);
  /*
     Inicio de conexão á rede Wi-Fi
  */
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(wifi_ssid);
  WiFi.begin(wifi_ssid, wifi_password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void reconnect() {
  /*
   *Loop de reconexão até que se conecte na rede Wi-Fi e no MQTT Broker
   */
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    // If you do not want to use a username and password, change next line to
    // if (client.connect("ESP8266Client")) {
    if (client.connect("changeMe")) {
      Serial.println("connected");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}
void loop() {
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();
  // Segundos de espera entre medidas 
      int sensorVal = analogRead(rainSensor);
      if (sensorVal < sensortrigger) {
        Serial.println("Rain");
        digitalWrite(dryLED, LOW);
        digitalWrite(rainLED, HIGH);
        client.publish(rain_sensor_topic, String("Raining").c_str(), true);
      }
      else {
        Serial.println("Not Rain");
        digitalWrite(rainLED, LOW);
        digitalWrite(dryLED, HIGH);
        client.publish(rain_sensor_topic, String("Not Raining").c_str(), true);
      }


    // Leitura da temperatura e pressão
      double temperature = bmp0.readTemperature (); // measure temperature
      Serial.print("Temperature = ");
      Serial.print(temperature, 3); // print with 3 decimal places
      Serial.println( " degrees Celsius");
      client.publish(bmp_temperature_topic, String(temperature).c_str(), true);

      double pressure = bmp0.readPressure (); // measure pressure
      Serial.print("Atmospheric pressure = ");
      Serial.print(pressure, 4); // print with 4 decimal places
      Serial.println( " mbar");
      client.publish(bmp_pressure_topic, String(pressure).c_str(), true);
      delay(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma que tem é usar o `delay()`, so que o problema é que usando isso o programa fica parado, logo a unica forma é usar os timers, dá start num timer para 10s, quando o timer terminar (passar os 10s) entao envia os dados, volta a dar reset ao timer.

É so pesquisar sobre uma biblioteca que goste e só usar, pode usar [esta](https://github.com/brunocalou/Timer) ou uma outra que goste.
Pode tambem fazer a sua propria biblioteca fazendo codigo em mais baixo nivel, ativando os registo e usando interrupções

Codigo exemplo usando [esta biblioteca](https://github.com/Fabio-Morais/Smart_Controller/blob/master/src/millisDelay.h) que usei no meu projeto:

```
#include millisDelay.h 

millisDelay ledDelay;

void setup()
{
 ledDelay.start(2000);
}
void loop(){
if(ledDelay.justFinished() )
   //faz algo (envia dados)
   ledDelay.start(2000); //dá reset no tempo
}
```

[.c e .h da biblioteca](https://github.com/Fabio-Morais/Smart_Controller/tree/master/src)